# How do I refer to a submodule's "full path" in ruby?

Tags: ruby, namespaces, module

In my app, I have

```
VeryUniqueModule::Foo
# and…
VeryUniqueModule::Bar
```

`Foo` and `Bar` are each for a different service. Part of my app has to dynamically figure out which module to refer to, which it capably does like so:

```
def service_api
  # @relevant_object.service is a string that is either 'Foo' or 'Bar'
  VeryUniqueModule.const_get(@relevant_object.service)
end
```

More on this later.

I just updated a library, and it now has its own top-level `Foo` class (which is bad design on its part). Now when I try to invoke `@relevant_object.service_api::A_CONSTANT`, my app complains that the *library's* `Foo` does not have `A_CONSTANT`.

Back to `service_api` above -- I thought that `const_get` was returning the class itself. In fact I know it is. If I fire it up in `irb` everything is as expected -- the return value is the class itself, and I can invoke things on the class. So…

1. How is it possible that there's a namespace conflict in the first place? I'm looking for `A_CONSTANT` on the *Class object* returned by `service_api`, not on a string that I'm `eval`ing or something funky like that -- there shouldn't be any namespace issues, I'm referring directly to an object!
2. If this is indeed a problem, how can I fix `service_api` so that it will return the, erm, "full path"?

Comment: What you are doing seems fine. There's probably an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
VeryUniqueModule.const_get('::VeryUniqueModule::' + @relevant_object.service)
```

And if that doesn't work, you could try bypassing `service_api` and doing this wherever you need `A_CONSTANT`:

```
Object.const_get('::VeryUniqueModule::' + @relevant_object.service + '::A_CONSTANT')
```

Note the `::` before `VeryUniqueModule`. I don't think it's strictly necessary in this case, but it could be useful in that it guarantees Ruby will look for `VeryUniqueModule` in the global namespace and not inside some other module.

Comment: There's no way any of this will work. `const_get` accepts only the name of constant, any `::` must be dealt with in other ways. E.g.: `class A; B = 42; end; Object.const_get("A::B") # => NameError: wrong constant name A::B`