# ruby thinks I'm referencing a top-level constant even when I specify the full namespace

Tags: ruby

In my app I have

```
class User
  include User::Foo
end
```

`User::Foo` is defined in app/models/user/foo.rb

Now I'm using a library that defines its own `Foo` class. I'm getting this error:

> warning: toplevel constant Foo referenced by User::Foo

`User` only refers to `Foo` with the full path, `User::Foo`, and `Foo` never actually refers to `Foo`.

What's going on?

**update:** just remembered I had the same problem before, seen here in question 1: [How do I refer to a submodule's "full path" in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455676/how-do-i-refer-to-a-submodules-full-path-in-ruby)

Comment: Can you post the lines where User references Foo?

Comment: https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html

Answer (score 5):

#### Make sure the User::Foo definition you want is visible

The message says: the only definition it found was at the top level. This is obviously suspicious since you went to the trouble of qualifying the name.

There isn't a good way to say you want a different ::User.  It's a class and ruby will look for a definition there, then at the top level. You need to somehow specify the module without referencing your class.

One way to fix this:

```
module Other
  class User
    include ::User::Foo
  end
end
```

Comment: could you elaborate on what you mean by "inner definition", "inner `User::Foo`" and "the reference"? thanks!

Comment: I've provided a complete minimal example of the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254496

Comment: @JohnBachir, i have provided [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254496/is-it-possible-to-give-a-sub-module-the-same-name-as-a-top-level-class/15716986#15716986)