# Is it possible to give a sub-module the same name as a top-level class?

Tags: ruby, class, namespaces, module

Background:

- [ruby thinks I'm referencing a top-level constant even when I specify the full namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208206)
- [How do I refer to a submodule's "full path" in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455676/)

Here's the problem, distilled down to a minimal example:

```
# bar.rb
class Bar
end

# foo/bar.rb
module Foo::Bar
end

# foo.rb
class Foo
  include Foo::Bar
end

# runner.rb
require 'bar'
require 'foo'
```

```
➔ ruby runner.rb
./foo.rb:2: warning: toplevel constant Bar referenced by Foo::Bar
./foo.rb:2:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
    from ./foo.rb:2
    from runner.rb:2:in `require'
    from runner.rb:2
```

Comment: I'm only including the gem, which then requires the library and does any other hooks that rails gems might do. So you're saying, maybe I can go into the vendor-provided gem and make everything explicitly `::Foo`? I think the problem is coming from the opposite side… when I include `User::Foo`, ruby searches the top-level for `Foo` first… See the thread I mention in the **update** above.

Comment: https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html

Answer (score 20):

Excellent; your code sample is very clarifying.  What you have there is a garden-variety circular dependency, obscured by the peculiarities of Ruby's scope-resolution operator.

When you run the Ruby code `require 'foo'`, ruby finds `foo.rb` and executes it, and then finds `foo/bar.rb` and executes that.  So when Ruby encounters your `Foo` class and executes `include Foo::Bar`, it looks for a constant named `Bar` in the class `Foo`, because that's what `Foo::Bar` denotes.  When it fails to find one, it searches other enclosing scopes for constants named `Bar`, and eventually finds it at the top level.  But *that* `Bar` is a class, and so can't be `include`d.

Even if you could persuade `require` to run `foo/bar.rb` before `foo.rb`, it wouldn't help; `module Foo::Bar` means "find the constant `Foo`, and if it's a class or a module, start defining a module within it called `Bar`".  `Foo` won't have been created yet, so the require will still fail.

Renaming `Foo::Bar` to `Foo::UserBar` won't help either, since the name clash isn't ultimately at fault.

So what *can* you do?  At a high level, you have to break the cycle somehow.  Simplest is to define `Foo` in two parts, like so:

```
# bar.rb
class Bar
  A = 4
end

# foo.rb
class Foo
  # Stuff that doesn't depend on Foo::Bar goes here.
end

# foo/bar.rb
module Foo::Bar
  A = 5
end

class Foo # Yep, we re-open class Foo inside foo/bar.rb
  include Bar # Note that you don't need Foo:: as we automatically search Foo first.
end

Bar::A      # => 4
Foo::Bar::A # => 5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks David -- take a look at my updated question, which now has a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well ... there is a way to do this without doing 
`class Foo
  include Bar
end`
in foo/bar.rb file.

You can in foo.rb do
`class Foo
  require 'foo/bar'
  include Foo::Bar
end`

Comment: Oh ... also renaming Foo::Bar to Foo::UserBar does help (at least Ruby 1.9)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more minimal example to demonstrate this behavior:

```rb
class Bar; end
class Foo
  include Foo::Bar
end
```

Output:

```
warning: toplevel constant Bar referenced by Foo::Bar
TypeError: wrong argument type Class (expected Module)
```

And here is even more minimal:

```rb
Bar = 0
class Foo; end
Foo::Bar
```

Output:

```
warning: toplevel constant Bar referenced by Foo::Bar
```

The explanation is simple, there is no bug: there is no `Bar` in `Foo`, and `Foo::Bar` is not yet defined.  For `Foo::Bar` to be defined, `Foo` has to be defined first.  The following code works fine:

```rb
class Bar; end
class Foo
  module ::Foo::Bar; end
  include Foo::Bar
end
```

However, there is something that is unexpected to me.  The following two blocks behave differently:

```rb
Bar = 0
class Foo; end
Foo::Bar
```

produces a warning:

```
warning: toplevel constant Bar referenced by Foo::Bar
```

but

```rb
Bar = 0
module Foo; end
Foo::Bar
```

produces an error:

```
uninitialized constant Foo::Bar (NameError)
```

Comment: Another very minimal example: `class Foo; include Foo::String; end`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another fun example:

```
module SomeName
  class Client
  end
end

module Integrations::SomeName::Importer
  def perform
    ...
    client = ::SomeName::Client.new(...)
    ...
  end
end
```

That produces:

`block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Integrations::SomeName::Importer::SomeName (NameError)`

Ruby (2.3.4) just goes to the first occurrence of "SomeName" it can find, not to the top-level.

A way to get around it is to either use better nesting of modules/classes(!!), or to use `Kernel.const_get('SomeName')`