# Top level constant referenced by warning for Mongoid model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have the following mongoid model that inherits from the Entry model:

```
class Entry::Twitter < Entry

  field :retweet_count, :type => Integer, :default => 0
  field :retweeted, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :favorited, :type => Boolean, :default => false

  # in_reply_to_screen_name, in_reply_to_status_id_str, in_reply_to_user_id_str
  field :reply, :type => Hash

  field :from, :type => Hash # user: id_str, name, screen_name
  field :time, :type => Time # created_at
  field :data, :type => Hash # entities (hashtags and user_mentions)
  field :assets, :type => Hash # urls from original entities
  field :service, :type => String, :default => "twitter"

  attr_accessible :assets

  # validations
  validates_presence_of :retweet_count, :from, :time, :data

  # override set_service cause of https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/303

  def set_service
    self.service = "twitter"
  end
end
```

When i try to reference it i get the following warning:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :001 > Entry::Twitter
(irb):1: warning: toplevel constant Twitter referenced by Entry::Twitter
=> Twitter
```

Instead of referencing to my model it references to the Top Level Constant Twitter that is defined by a gem.

What can i do to fix this? I don't want to use another name for my class.

Comment: Which gem do you mean exaclty? this one: https://github.com/sferik/twitter? I have a similar problem, and loading error..

Comment: Your problem is related to how Ruby handles scoping. Here's a pretty good description of what's happening: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6282245/279024

Comment: @rubiii I already have seen this. But i dont know how to apply this to my specific problem.

Comment: @Mattherick As the problem is not exactly in your code, but in the gem's code referencing the `Twitter` constant, I would just rename your class to `TwitterEntry`.

Comment: not the same but: `Entry::Twitter == ::Twitter`
`=> true`

`Entry::Twitter == Twitter`
`=> true`

Comment: Where in your app (what file/path) is this code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the solution:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6931

I just added `require_dependency 'entry/twitter'` to every files that references `Entry::Twitter` to avoid this problem, and it works fine now.