# rails sti and namespace duplicates model name

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, sti

in my rails app i have models like this

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
class Account::Bonus < Account
class Account::Virtual < Account
...more
```

And like this

```
class DiscountSystem  < ActiveRecord::Base
class DiscountSystem::MyFirst < DiscountSystem
class DiscountSystem::MySecond < DiscountSystem
```

Account and DiscountSystem - STI models

After that, I wish that DiscountSystem had Account, account only for DiscountSystem, and name new model Account::DiscountSystem

If I understand correctly, "DiscountSystem" for "Account" is in namespace "Account".

them:

```
class Account::DiscountSystem < Account
  belongs_to :discount_system,class_name: '::DiscountSystem',:foreign_key => :owner_id
end
```

and

```
 class DiscountSystem  < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :account, :class_name => 'Account::DiscountSystem',:foreign_key => :owner_id
 end
```

if i try in console

```
>> DiscountSystem::MyFirst.all
LoadError: Expected C:/.../app/models/account/discount_system.rb to define DiscountSystem
>> DiscountSystem.all
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for DiscountSystem:Module
```

why?
I'm probably a very misunderstood concept of namespace.

Of course, if i rename Account::DiscountSystem to Account::ForDiscountSystem, everything works well. Why name in namespace Account "rewrite" root name DiscountSystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution here.

[Top level constant referenced by warning for Mongoid model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932265/top-level-constant-referenced-by-warning-for-mongoid-model)
and here

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6931

```
require_dependency 'account/discount_system'

class DiscountSystem  < ActiveRecord::Base
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using `class Account::Bonus < Account` but `class Bonus < Account` instead. You are basically repeating yourself with the `Account::` prefix as it already inherits from DiscountSystem.

Then you can also drop the `class_name` param in the `belongs_to`/`has_one` method call.

Doing this will make your code easier to understand and is more in the spirit of Rails.

Comment: I chose this solution because the accounts are already quite a lot - so far more than 10, because for each type of account I have to overload the methods and variables.
I thought semantically correct select is not in %AccountName%, and not in the Account %AccountName%-and in naymspace Account::%AccountName%
In fact, in the example Account::Bonus-This is the invented "substitutes" to the other entities of the system, who have an account.
I would love for the simplicity of the code is added to the Account name of the entity, which it is,but in the "duplication" of variables comes out this error.