# active_record configuration from yaml file: debuglevel

Tags: ruby, activerecord, logging, jruby, yaml

I'm trying to configure the debuglevel for active-record logger from a YAML configuration file but get the following error, how could i do this other than using a number in the YAML ?

```
sample.rb:30 warning: toplevel constant LEVEL referenced by Logger::LEVEL
"DEBUG"
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with String failed
```

here is the sample.rb

```
require 'java'
require 'active_record'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
require 'yaml'
require 'logger'

def get_jar_path
  if __FILE__[/.+\.jar!/] #in case run from JAR
    scriptpath = __FILE__[/(.*)\/.+\.jar!/]
    $1[6..-1]
  else #in case run with jRuby
    '..'
  end
end

def load_config
  path = "#{get_jar_path}/#{File.basename(__FILE__, ".*")}.configuration.yml"
  p path
  $conf = YAML::load_file(path)
end

load_config
LEVEL = $conf['debug_level'] #string 'DEBUG' from configuration file
$log = Logger.new( "#{get_jar_path}/log_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt", 'monthly' )
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = $log
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG #works
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::LEVEL #doesn't work
p ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level
$log.info "start #{__FILE__}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The available log levels are: :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal,
>   and :unknown, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5
>   respectively.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

```
require 'logger'

puts Logger::DEBUG

--output:--
0


str = "DEBUG"
puts Logger.const_get(str)

--output:--
0
```

So you should do something like:

```
level = $conf['debug_level'] #string 'DEBUG' from configuration file
$log = Logger.new( "#{get_jar_path}/log_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt", 'monthly' )
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = $log
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger.const_get(level)
```

I'm not sure why you thought defining a constant, LEVEL, in the current scope would make that constant appear in the Logger scope, so that you could write Logger::LEVEL.  You essentially did this:

```
MYCONST = "hello"

module SomeModule
  SOMECONST = "goodbye"
end
```

You can write:

```
puts MYCONST   #=>hello
```

..and you can write:

```
puts SomeModule::SOMECONST  #goodbye
```

..but you cannot write:

```
puts SomeModule::MYCONST

--output:--
1.rb:10:in `<main>': uninitialized constant SomeModule::MYCONST (NameError)
```

Comment: thanks, const_get was what i needed, any idea how to get rid of the warning: toplevel constant LEVEL referenced by Logger::LEVEL

Comment: And here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254496/is-it-possible-to-give-a-sub-module-the-same-name-as-a-top-level-class